# How to solve issue get date 1970-01-01 from datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker

I am using datepicker and function. The function is to use convert from `dd-mm-yyyy` to `yyyy-mm-dd` style. Current situation I have recorded date in database, database format is `yyyy-mm-dd` so I need to convert to `dd-mm-yyyy` style first for easy to read. So during submission I need to convert back to `yyyy-mm-dd`(here I use the function).

I opened a form that already have recorded read from database including date, for instance the date is `26-03-2020`. So I try to submit the form without change the date. The problem comes here whereby the date is set to `1970-01-01`, why this happen? see below.

I am using this [bootstrap-datepicker](https://github.com/uxsolutions/bootstrap-datepicker)

I have tried both below but this is what I get:

`var actualDate = $('#actualDate').val();   // If i try this I will get NaN-NaN-NaN`

`var actualDate = $('#actualDate').datepicker('getDate');   // If i try this I will get 1970-01-01`

[image]

[image]

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="actualDate"></input>
```

**JS**

```
$.ajax({
    url : url_projectList + '/1st_api',
    crossDomain: true,
    type : 'POST',
    dataType : 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify({project_id: id}),
    success: function(response){

        var actualDate = $('#actualDate').val();       // If i try this I will get NaN-NaN-NaN
        var actualDate = $('#actualDate').datepicker('getDate');     // If i try this I will get 1970-01-01

        if ($("#actualDate").val() == ""){
            var project_start_date = null;  // This is working fine
        } else {
            project_start_date = sendDate(actualDate);   // Here is the error coming
        }

        console.log(project_start_date)  // I got NaN-NaN-NaN

        $.ajax({
            url : url_projectList + '/2nd_api',
            type : 'POST',
            dataType : 'json',
            data: params,
        });
    }
});

function sendDate(input_date){

    proc_date = new Date(input_date)
    year = proc_date.getYear() + 1900
    month = proc_date.getMonth() + 1
    day = proc_date.getDate()

    if (month < 10)
    {
      month = "0" + month;
    }
    if (day < 10)
    {
      day = "0" + day;
    }

    return year +"-"+ month +"-"+ day;
}
```

**DATEPICKER**

```
$('#actualDate').datepicker({
    language: 'en',
    format: "dd-mm-yyyy",
    clearButton: true,
    toggleSelected: true,
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true,
    ignoreReadonly: true,
});
```

Comment: It is not clear which DatePicker you are using. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: just update the link for datepicker

Answer (score 0):

you should change the format of datapicker

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    format: 'yyyy/dd/mm'
});
```

for futher info visit

> https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/